# Why won't this CDATE format to mm/yyyy?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert a string *"mm/dd/yy hh:mm AM/PM"* to a date *"mm/yyyy"*

Why is the following code outputting `11-2-2015`?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim yourStringDate As String
    Dim yourDateVariable As Date

    yourStringDate = "11/2/15 12:00 AM"        
    yourDateVariable = Format(CDate(yourStringDate), "mm/yyyy")        
    MsgBox yourDateVariable

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how about

```
Dim yourStringDate As Date
yourStringDate = DateValue("11/2/15 12:00 AM")
MsgBox Format(yourStringDate, "mm/yyyy")
```

or in your original format

```
Dim yourStringDate As String
Dim yourDateVariable As Date
yourStringDate = "11/2/15 12:00 AM"
yourDateVariable = CDate(yourStringDate)
MsgBox Format(yourDateVariable, "mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Ultimately, I want to copy values from one Excel workbook and paste the values into another.  The values, however, are stored as plain text, so I want to iterate through the pasted range and format all the strings to `mm/yyyy`.  I was just using this example as a test.

Answer (score -1):

I think lower case mm is for minutes, try MM for month.